# Limit as $x\to 0$ the same if $x$ restricted to be inside a ball?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, limits

Here $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $B(0, R)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is the ball of radius $R > 0$ centered at the origin.

> Is the limit of $f$ as $x\to 0$ always the same as the limit as $x$ goes to zero but when it is restricted to be in a ball of fixed radious $R$ around $0$?
> $$
> \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \overset{?}{=} \lim_{\substack{x\to 0 \\ x\in B(0, R)}} f(x)
> $$

I never see this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I suppose this should always be true when $f$ is continuous

Comment: This seems to follow from the definition of limit.  Given your $\epsilon$, pick $\delta$ to be smaller than $R$, which is always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Randall's comment written out more explicitly:

$a = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ says: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - a| < \varepsilon$.

So pick some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists a corresponding $\delta > 0$. Set $\delta' := \min\{ R, \delta \}$. Then $\delta' \leq \delta$, so $|x| < \delta'$ still implies $|f(x) - a| < \varepsilon$. But now we also know all $|x| < \delta'$ satisfy $x \in B(0,R)$, since $\delta' \le R$. This shows the two limits are the same.

Comment: This would be $\lVert x\rVert<\delta$ here, not absolute value.

Comment: The notation $|x| < \delta$ obviously doesn't mean absolute value since $x$ is a vector. The typical understood default is L2 norm. And even if this wasn't the understood default, what you are saying does not even matter. As your own comment points out, L2 and L1 (or other Lp) norms are the same in the limit, for this particular application

Answer (score 1):

The potential issue could be that with a certain norm, you may only consider some limits along a path, e.g. along $x_2=mx_1$ for instance and have an existing path limit but not a global limit.

But in $\mathbb R^n$ all norms are equivalent, so the coordinate-wise $x_i\to 0$ convergence is the same as convergence in norm $\lVert x\rVert\to 0$ and the limit is independent of the ball chosen.

Said in a different manner, you can always get an isotropic ball $\lVert x\rVert_\infty<\delta\implies \lVert x\rVert<R$ for a given norm which take care about limits along a path.